# How to hide categories with no active products?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Is there a way to hide categories that don't have active products?

Or, even better, only show categories that have active products **and** stock.

Comment: The question is whether this is a good idea. Users are confused when they change the menu.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to do this is to only rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` block:

=> **In the method `_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml()` you want to replace the loop**

```
foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child->getIsActive()) {
        $activeChildren[] = $child;
    }
}
```

**=> with this:**

```
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive() && $this->_hasProducts($child->entity_id)) {
            $activeChildren[] = $child;
        }
    }
```

**=> and similarly in the method `renderCategoriesMenuHtml()` replace the code**

```
 foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeCategories[] = $child;
        }
    }
```

**=> with this:**

```
    foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive() && $this->_hasProducts($child->entity_id)) {
            $activeCategories[] = $child;
        }
    }
```

**=> Finally add the method we were just using in our code:**

```
protected function _hasProducts($category_id) {
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    return ( $products->count() > 0 )  ? true : false;
}
```

Bear in mind that the method checks each category individually by using the catalog/category model. So, if you have many categories, you might want to rewrite the code to not run into performance issues. In a smaller store we are running, this works fine.

Comment: Is it possible to box this up into an extension that can be dropped in to local folder? Worried about the code being overwritten in future Magento updates.

Answer (score 10):

There is no built-in feature for hiding empty categories (but you can manually select Is active = No for each category in admin area->catalog->manage categories)

Here is [a link on a great post from Josh Prattski's blog](http://prattski.com/2011/10/06/magento-module-hide-empty-categories/), where he wrote step-by-step walkthrough on how-to make an extension for this purpose.

Comment: This looks good, but for whatever reason isn't working in our store... any ideas how to debug? Not getting any error messages. Followed the instructions to a tee, but no change in frontend. Have already disabled, then re-enabled compiler, and cleared cache etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to hide them in the catalog navigation you could add an if condition in the template to check for amount of products in that category.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this would help too.

Go to the backend of your webshop.

> Then to `Catalog > Category > Manage Category`, choose your category,
>   and select the `Display settings` tab.

The label `Display Mode` could be set to

> `Show static block only`.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is to create a template category tree and implement a condition function which renders the category tree:

```
foreach ($children as $child) 
{
    if ($child->getIsActive() && $this->_hasProducts($child->entity_id)) 
    {
        $activeChildren[] = $child;
    }
}
function _hasProducts:

    protected function _hasProducts($category_id) {
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    return ( $products->count() > 0 )  ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what I've did to hide empty categories is to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree` `load()` function.
I've to join product collection with category collection like below.

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

 $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('product_category' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/category_product_index')),
        'product_category.product_id = e.entity_id',
        array('')
    );
    $collection->getSelect()->where('product_category.category_id = '.$this->_table.'.entity_id');
    $select->columns(array('product_count' => $collection->getSelectCountSql()));
```

add this code before `$arrNodes = $this->_conn->fetchAll($select);` this line.

And wrap this code with this condition, this class called from frontend and backend model also

```
  if(!Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn())
```

I've added extra field product_count which contains actual active product count.

I am using a 3rd party module to display category on the top menu and I've put condition based on product count when the menu is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute following sql to disable all categories without products.

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `status`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attr` ON `attr`.`attribute_code` = 'is_active'
AND `attr`.`entity_type_id` = 3
AND `status`.`attribute_id` = `attr`.`attribute_id`
SET `status`.`value` = IF((SELECT COUNT(`index`.`product_id`)
    FROM `catalog_category_product_index` AS `index`
    WHERE `index`.`category_id` = `status`.`entity_id` GROUP BY `index`.`category_id`) > 0, 1, 0)
WHERE `status`.`store_id` = 0
```

More details you can find here http://quicktips.ru/all/hide-all-categories-without-products-and-show-categories-with-pr/