# Getting Subcategories even if product count for each is 0

Tags: product, category, magento2.3, sub-categories

In my module, I am getting the current ID and then using the category repository and the "getChildren" method. This works great, except it doesn't return child categories with product counts of 0.

How would I get around this?

"getAllChildren" seemed promising, but returned all descendants, whereas I'm just looking for the immediate children, regardless of product counts.

Edit: For testing purposes, I've added products to these categories that aren't showing up. Their ID's still aren't being returned via the GetChildren method.

Comment: Categories are full of strange limitations. I have a different but similar challenge and ended up using getAllChildren and adding a condition later to filter out the crap (for example it returns that parent itself as first element)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `getChildrenCategories()` instead? If in doubt `var_dump($catergory->getIsActive())`. Although I've generally encountered the other way. I've had to do work to hide empty categories.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/80/70343

Comment: `getChildrenCategories()` returns the same categories, unfortunately